# Text in a table column is not having constant line height

Tags: html, css

I have a table in the below format

```
 <tr >
      <td>
          <span class="boldText">OfficeType</span>
      </td>
      <td>
             <p class="mb0">BDA REGISTRATION INVESTIGATION & CORRECTIONS</p>
     </td>
 </tr>
.mb0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The expectation is the text OfficeType and BDA REGISTRATION INVESTIGATION & CORRECTIONS should appear in the same line with extra text to wrap to the next line.The text wraps to the next line but the OfficeType and BDA REGISTRATION are not aligned in the same line.Can you please help me in this,what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can u create a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add valign=top to TD elements

```
<tr>
      <td valign=top>
          <span class="boldText">OfficeType</span>
      </td>
      <td valign=top>
             <p class="mb0">BDA REGISTRATION INVESTIGATION & CORRECTIONS</p>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks hanzala The alignment problem got solved how to increase the line-height for the wrapped text.The text may come in a single line or a double line and it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike p tag, span does not have a css attribute of

```
"display:block"
```

so you can add it to p tags style to have equal line height

Answer (score 0):

If you press F12 and take a look at the box model you'll see that p comes with a default top margin but span doesn't.

The simplest way to deal with this is to be consistent with your use of p and span tags across all cells.